# X11 Forwarding not working on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ssh, xorg, x11-forwarding

I've read numerous similar questions but many are outdated and nothing seems to work.
I have an homePC `<remotehome>` and a laptop `<locallaptop>`, both running `Ubuntu 22.04`.

I'm away from home, I can ssh into `<remotehome>` both with psw or private key.

```
sudo ssh -o HostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa -o PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-rsa -X -p 2022 remoteuser@<remotehome>
```

(the port is 2022 because of port forwarding on my home router, idk if relevant)

Once on remote host, `xdg-open` or `firefox` commands give me:

```
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
Error: cannot open display: localhost:10.0
```

Running `xlogo` on remote terminal actually opens a window on my local desktop.

**Useful Info:**

```
df -H
```

on remote terminal, plenty of space.

```
ls -l ~/.Xauthority
```

output:

```
-rw------- 1 remoteuser remoteuser 69 mar 22 15:23 /home/remoteuser/.Xauthority
```

X11 Forwarding is enabled on `<remotehome>`

```
X11Forwarding yes
```

in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

On client  X11 Forwarding is enabled.

```
Host *
ForwardX11 yes
```

in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`

`xhost` command gives the same output from both the remote and local terminal:

```
access control enabled, only authorized clients can connect
SI:localuser:<my-username-in-local-laptop>
```

The $XAUTHORITY var on my local desktop is:

```
/run/user/1000/.mutter-Xwaylandauth.PLS211
```

I've tried the solution proposed [here](https://itslinuxfoss.com/x11-connection-rejected-because-of-wrong-authentication/) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162979/annoying-message-x11-connection-rejected-because-of-wrong-authentication-while) and [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/x11-forwarding-ssh-connection-rejected-because-wrong-authentication). Nothing seems to work. Any help to debug this issue is really appreciated.

Comment: If `xlogo` forwards successfully, then X11 forwarding is working - what may not be working is the forwarding of snaps (which appears to be because the snap home interface does not allow access to the hidden .Xauthority file) - see for example [ssh connection. X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/709789/65304) and [Canonical Snapcraft: X11 Forwarding using SSH](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/x11-forwarding-using-ssh/2381/8)